# magento google analitycs multistore

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.7

I've a magento installation with 3 websites whit 3 storeview each. Everything works fine a part google analitycs. I want to have a different account associated to each website to have separate statistics. The main site works perfectly but the other 2 no. I don't see any traffics, visit piratically nothing.
Thanks for your support,
bye
Enrico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goto Admin -> Config -> Google Api

Then change the "Current Configuration Scope" for the other 2 websites and enter each GA Account Number.

View source on each domain to check if the GA Code is there and correct.

You may also want to take a look @ 
[GA Tracking Multiple Domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I found the problem. The 3 stores are with different 2 themes, 1 alone on the main site and another for the other 2. The problem is the theme, if I change the theme I've the right code on the page. Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: The problem was the theme, now all works fine!Thanks